# Center using padding instead of margin using CSS (no additional wrapper DIV)

Tags: html, css

I want to create a nav bar with the content centered and constrained to a width.

I am able to center it using

```
margin: auto;
```

But I actually want the background to stretch the whole screen width.  So I tried

```
padding: auto;
```

But that didn't work.  The closest I can think of (as I write this question) was:

```
padding-left: calc((1vw - 1080px)/2);
padding-right: calc((1vw - 1080px)/2);
```

https://codepen.io/trajano/pen/NWPZyEX

Comment: Can you use flexbox?

Comment: Maybe you can provide the answer to that.  But if I use flexbox won't I need to add extra HTML to pad?

Comment: Ok, i just saw the codepen and I understood well the question: I think you want to achieve it having the div full-width and only the content constrained to the fixed width.

Comment: `padding:auto;` doesn't work because it's not a valid setting. That's not what padding is for.

Answer (score 2):

I was actually close

```
padding-left: calc((100% - 1080px)/2);
padding-right: calc((100% - 1080px)/2);
```

With SCSS I can create the two mixins to set the responsive widths like this

```css
@mixin global-width {
  margin: auto;
  @include for-tablet-landscape-up {
    width: 800px;
  }
  @include for-desktop-up {
    width: 1080px;
  }
}

@mixin padded-width {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  @include for-tablet-landscape-up {
    padding-left: calc((100% - 800px)/2);
    padding-right: calc((100% - 800px)/2);
  }
  @include for-desktop-up {
    padding-left: calc((100% - 1080px)/2);
    padding-right: calc((100% - 1080px)/2);
  }
}
```